# drupal 7 contact us form send email

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

i using contact module to send email to my email box,how to custom the email body? the default is:

```
the user name (http://example.com/user/3) use
http://example.com/contact ...

the message body
```

i have used `hook_form_alter` adding some fields to the contact us form.eg:phone, address,company name.email dress, how to make them shows in the email body. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform). You will not need to implement any hooks to add fields or configure which fields to be sent via email.

It's a lot easier that Drupal's contact module

Answer (score 2):

Muhammad has suggested the good solution that we should use [Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform) to add fields. That way you don't need to write any code.

For your specific need, you can use [hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) which will help you to alter an email message and you can add your extra fields in email body.

Comment: could you give me with more detail if i using hook_mail_alter thank you

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [contact.module](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/modules/contact/contact.module#L170) there are a few predefined, hardcoded variabels. IF you add your own fields to the form, they are not available for the mail.

In order to make them available there, you'd need to write, register and write your own mail-handler;

Implement [hook_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7)

```
function email_example_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  global $user;

  $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['language']->language,
  );

  switch ($key) {
    case 'contact_message':
      $message['subject'] = t('E-mail sent from @site-name', array('@site-name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')), $options);
      $message['body'][] = t('@name sent you the following message:', array('@name' => $user->name), $options);
      $message['body'][] = check_plain($params['message']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Then a method to send the mail:

```
function email_example_mail_send($form_values) {
  $module = 'email_example';
  $key = 'contact_message';

  $to = $form_values['email'];
  $from = variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com');

  $params = $form_values;
  $language = language_default();
  $send = TRUE;
  $result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
  if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

This method would then be called from within a custom *submit handler*:

```
function email_example_contact_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  email_example_mail_send($form_state);
}
```

Which you register in a `hook_form_alter` (I don't know the exact form_id for core contact form, place that where I put `contact`):

```
function email_example_contact_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit']['my_very_own_submit'] = array();
}
```

[from example for developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples)

Comment: your mean i must create a module?i put your code in a module file,but it still can't work

Comment: Off course you must program a module, that is what you asked about, not?

Answer (score 2):

[Entityforms](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) module uses the standard Drupal fields which means you can use any standard Drupal fields. For those of you who have used Webforms, this module brings Webform's functionality into the "standard" Drupal field / entity world.

While Webform is a great module with a huge following, it does not integrate with standard Drupal field or entity aware modules. So for Drupal 7 sites, it is recommended to use Entityforms module!

Like Webform, it integrates well with Rules module for form submission notifications and allows for complex notifications logic.